# iOS DispatchQueue safety of caching on background thread

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I am creating images asynchronously, and then updating the UI on the main thread. e.g.

```
imageLoadingQueue.async {

    // Creates a new image, caches it.
    let newImage = ImageManager.shared.buildImage(named: ...)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        view.setImage(newImage)
    }
}
```

However, I'm concerned about operations on the background thread, pertaining to caching.

In this case, the ImageManager singleton is responsible for both the creation of the required image, and the caching of it (through an `NSCache` property on the shared instance).

Q. is it safe for the `buildImage(named:)` method to cache the built image in a property on 'shared'?

If it is not, would it be safe to for the `buildImage(named:)` method to perform its caching on the main thread, thusly:

```
func buildImage(named name: String) -> UIImage
{
    let newImage = ... // Do the work.

    // Cache the result on the main thread, to our property.
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageCache[key] = 
    }

    return newImage
}
```

OR...

Another possibility: break up the image creation from the caching. I do not like this artificial break-up as it leaves the consumer of the ImageManager to do more, but will adopt it is safer.

```
imageLoadingQueue.async {

    // Build the image. Performs no caching.
    let newImage = ImageManager.shared.buildImage(named: ...)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        // Cache the image now that we're on the main thread.
        ImageManager.shared.cacheImage(image, key: "foo")
        view.setImage(newImage)
    }
}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit open-ended. However, I think the answer you're looking for is pretty straightforward. The [`NSCache` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscache) says, in part:

> - You can add, remove, and query items in the cache from different threads without having to lock the cache yourself.

So for your question,

> Q. is it safe for the buildImage(named:) method to cache the built image in a property on 'shared'?

Yes, you can modify the cache on any thread without taking your own thread-safety precautions, like dispatching asynchronously to the main thread.

Comment: Thank you. It was a more a question of safety in operating on managed memory on a background thread (i.e. safety of any property setting, whether it's a Dictionary, Array, some custom Struct, etc.) rather than just NSCache, but that information is also very useful. Big cheers.

Comment: To answer that question in a nutshell: no, it is not safe in general to concurrently modify mutable state from multiple threads.

Comment: Oh. Rats. In that case, do you have a suggestion for a pattern to use, in the case where I need to set data on an object when it's being used on a background thread?  Is it feasible for that object to set the data via DispatchQueue.main.async { .. } ?

Comment: @Womble, you can use any serial queue, not neccessarily the main-queue, for synchronization purposes

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev Aye, but the issue here is where I need to hand off a task (image building, caching) on another thread, but I need that service to be able to cache the results safely. So is it safe for the ImageManager singleton to call main.async before caching the data? Cheers.

Comment: @Womble, doing anything in main queue, also means doing it in the single thread. It should be safe in all ways, but it could cause your UI to become less responsive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on thread safety of the methods/objects you use inside the ImageManager.

For instance if you create **UIImage**... they are thread safe in **iOS10**, but **they are not in any older iOS**: it means in older iOS you have to create UIImage in the main thread, or you risk get a crash.

If you look up AppleDocs on the methods and objects you use, you shall quickly be able to find references to thread safety (use these keywords).

Comment: Nit: `UIImage`'s most common creation method, [`imageNamed:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624146-imagenamed?language=objc), has been thread-safe since iOS _9_.

Comment: I agree, but I also assume that not all the images are available locally so I can't be sure imageNamed will always be used. My point is to verify methods used for thread safety.